# What is meant by a vector space OVER a complex subfield?

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis

I am currently going over some some proofs but trying to wrap my head around this sentence "Let $V$ be a Vector Space **OVER** a complex subfield $\mathbb{F}$". I am just looking for a rough understanding of the use of the word 'over' in this context. Some intuition that I can build upon. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what a vector space is? By definition, vector spaces are always defined over some field.

Comment: you may think about the scalar multiplication, scalar is from the $\mathbb{F}$, that multiply a vector in V

Comment: $\mathbb{F} \times V \to V$

Comment: We have the operation of scalar multiple $\lambda x$ for $\lambda$ in that field.  One or more of the postulates for "vector space" specify properties of this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your functional-analysis and complex-analysis tags, presumably you know that there are vector spaces defined over the real numbers $\mathbb R$, as well as vector spaces defined over the complex numbers $\mathbb C$. The common feature in these two different kinds of vector spaces is that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ are the "field of scalars". The field of scalars is referred to in several portions of the definition of a vector field, such as the distributive law of scalar multiplication over scalar addition, which has the following forms depending on whether one is using $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ as the field of scalars:

> For all $x,y \in \mathbb R$ and $v \in V$, $(x+y)v = xv + yv$.

> For all $x,y \in \mathbb C$ and $v \in V$, $(x+y)v = xv + yv$.

One can generalize these two examples, obtaining a definition of a vector space $V$ defined over any field $\mathbb F$. For example, start the definition of a vector space over the field $\mathbb R$, and then everywhere the definition refers to a scalar in $\mathbb R$, cross that out and replace it by a scalar in $\mathbb F$. The distributive law of scalar addition over scalar multiplication will become

> For all $x,y \in \require{cancel} \cancel{\mathbb R} \mathbb F$ and $v \in V$, $(x+y)v = xv + yv$.

The field $\mathbb C$ has many, many subfields; the first one that jumps into my mind is $\mathbb Q[i] = \{a+bi \mid a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$, and so now you can define and study vector spaces over $\mathbb Q[i]$. Presumably the text you are reading has some specific subfields of $\mathbb C$ in mind, to be used as the "field of scalars" for some vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you Lee for the thorough explanantion. I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

When we say $V$ is a vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}$, we mean that whenever we have an operation (typically multiplication) involving both vectors and scalars, the vectors come from $V$ and the scalars come from $\mathbb{F}$.

For example, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a two-dimensional vector space over the real numbers, and the scalar multiplication is defined as $\lambda (x, y) = (\lambda x, \lambda y)$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.